# How to populate dropdown field pre-selected with the existing data from another MySQL table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

In my database I have 2 tables:

[image: tabels]
To insert data, I have a form that populates dropdown options from the table `formulation`. This is what the insert form for formulation dropdown looks like:

```
<?php
$formulation = '';
$query = "SELECT * FROM formulation";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $formulation .= '<option value="' . $row["formulationID"] . '">' . $row["formulation_name"] . '</option>';
}
?>

<select>
    <option value="">Select formulation</option>
    <?php echo $formulation; ?>
</select>
```

Now I am working on the ‘Update’ form. But my question is how can I populate the ‘Formulation’ field dropdown with the data from the `formulation` table (like as the insert form) but pre-selected with the existing `formulation` value for the `name` from the `items` table? Like this image below:
[image: UpdateForm]

I am having problem with how I should build the form. How should I proceed with this form?

```
<?php
$output = array('data' => array());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output['data'][] = array(
        $row['name'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>

<form action=" " method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text"><br>
        <label>Formulation</label>
        <select >
            <!--What should be the codes here? -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: The general idea is to update particular item? So update action actually update the items table?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. @Solmyr

Answer (score 2):

***Note:*** I'm not a user of `mysqli` so maybe there will be some error, but you will get the idea. This will not tackle the update part, just the populate part

Since you are editing a certain item, I will assume that you have something to get the item's `itemID`.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemID = ?";
$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("s", $yourItemID);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$itemName = $result['name'];
$itemFormulation = $result['formulation_fk'];

//now you have the name and the formulation of that certain item
?>

<form action=" " method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>"><br>
        <label>Formulation</label>
        <select >
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM formulation";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['formulationID']; ?>" <?php echo ($row['formulationID'] == $itemFormulation) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                    <?php echo $row['formulation_name']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

I changed the code to better suit the problem, there may be typos, just comment for clarification

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm looking into it to adapt with my existing system. I'll let you know surely after.  :)

Comment: I'm not sure of the functions I used, so just replace them when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand Your question... You have to put Your result into a string. For example:

```
<?php
$output = array('data' => array());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

$option = '';
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
     $name=$row['name'],
    $option.='<option value="$name">$name</option>'
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>

<form action=" " method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text"><br>
        <label>Formulation</label>
        <select >
            <?=$option?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

I hope to be of help

Comment: How would this know what kind of formulation that certain item have? And from what I see, you are embedding the name of the items rather than the name of the formulation in the `select`

Comment: All my web pages work with this method. The element name can be replaced with another element.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
$itemsSql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemId = 5";
$itemQuery = $connect->query($sql);
$item = $itemQuery->fetch_assoc();

$formulationsSql = "SELECT * FROM formulation";
$formulationsQuery = $connect->query($sql);
$formulations = $itemQuery->fetch_assoc();
?>

<form action="updateItem" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Item Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?= $item[0]['name']; ?>"><br>
        <label>Formulation</label>
        <select>
            <?php foreach($formulations as $formulation){
            echo '<option value="'. $formulation['formulationId'].'">' .
                   $formulation['formulation_name'] . '</option>';
            } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```